# Guess and Prove a formula for an alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to guess and prove a formula for

$1 − 2 + 3 − 4 + · · · + (−1)^{n−1}n$

I'm pretty sure it is just $\sum_{i=1}^n n(-1)^{n-1}$ but how do I prove this?

I believe I am supposed to use induction somehow...

Comment: Forgot: this must be true for any value n>0

Comment: This question does not make sense

Comment: I suspect you are supposed to produce a closed expression.  It might be worth looking at the first six or so partial sums

Comment: $f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor\cdot(-1)^{n+1}$

Comment: @user3283585 :  You are not asked for a formula such as $\sum_{i=1}^n n(-1)^{n-1}$ : this would be childish. You are asked to guess a formula without $\sum$ in it. And then, to prouve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed-form is $f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor\cdot(-1)^{n+1}$

If you want to use induction, then it might be easier to prove this:

$f(n)=\cases
 {
    -n  /2 & \text{$n$ is even}\\
   (n+1)/2 & \text{$n$ is odd }\\
 }
$

Comment: What's the down-vote for?????

Comment: This makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: @user3283585: You're welcome.